# Add missing keys into array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this, with missing keys:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Bill"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "billy@kid.com"
}
```

How can I add missing keys to it with empty strings as values? I want this as a result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Bill"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(13) "billy@kid.com"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your questions is very vague and hard to understand exactly what you want, from my interpretation it seems you want to insert a key into the array moving the current keys along the index line.

you may want to try something like this:

```
function cleanArray(&$array)
{
    end($array);
    $max = key($array); //Get the final key as max!
    for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
    {
        if(!isset($array[$i]))
        {
            $array[$i] = '';
        }
    }
}

cleanArray($array);
```

Comment: `end($array)` returns the last _value_, `key()` expects an array -- this code throws an error: `PHP Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given`

Comment: The missing keys are added at the end of the array, so it can be useful to reorder them by applying `ksort` to the resulting array

Answer (score 11):

Similar to Rinuwise's answer:

```
$t = array( 0 => "Bill",
            2 => "billy@kid.com"
          );


$u = $t + array_fill_keys( range(min(array_keys($t)),
                                 max(array_keys($t))
                                ),
                           ''
                           );

ksort($u);

var_dump($u);
```

Comment: if you omit `ksort($u)` and use `0` instead of `min(...)` this is the *best* answer: key order is maintained and makes no assumption about where the max key resides. downside: not sure about performance, and not the most intuitive-looking solution. in summary: `$t + array_fill_keys(range(0,max(array_keys($t))),'')`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to automate setting the empty keys, you can do

```
$keys = array_keys($array);

$maxkey = end($keys); // it will fill only the values between 0 and last key

for ($i = 0; $i < $maxkey; $i++) {
    if (!array_key_exists($i, $array)) {
        $array[$i] = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the array keys aren't sorted in ascending order?

Comment: use foreach loop instead of for

Comment: json he is not looping the array, he is looping the size of the keys, there totally different!

Comment: @BoltClock , if they are not sorted in ascending order, then the logic changes quite a lot, if you want to use the same function for ascending and descending :) Given the example, I think that he wants to fill the gaps in a simple array with ascending key numbers.

Comment: The use of `end` here makes no sense. Use `max` instead, so you'll get the highest key.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a bit different answer on how to do it without looping by taking advantage of the array sum operator.

```
<?php

$array = array(
    0 => "Bill",
    2 => "billy@kid.com",
);

// If min and max are static, use numbers instead of getting them from the array
$keys = array_keys($array);
$all = array_fill(min($keys), max($keys) - min($keys) + 1, "");
$filled = $array + $all;

// If you want keys in order
ksort($filled);

var_dump($filled);
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite old - but I think we can do a little better than the given answers, by providing a three-line solution to fill missing keys in a numerically indexed `$array` with a `$defaultVal` - *without* needing to sort anything first - and still getting a sorted result.

Furthermore, we only do as many loop iterations as there are entries in our original array - and leave the generation of the potentially much larger set of missing indices to the internal php c-code, which can optimize its functions better than we can optimize our userland code.

```
// array_fill generates a sorted array,
// we merely overwrite its values at certain indices.
// Thus, $newArray will end up sorted,
// even if $array wasn't

$newArray = array_fill(0, max(array_keys($array)), $defaultVal);
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    $newArray[$key] = $val;
}
```

If you need something like this in a context of gigantic arrays or huge numbers of iterations - you might also benefit from using `SplFixedArray`, which we can use since we know the size of the array - and which is significantly more resource-friendly. You will have to replace the `array_fill`-part by an explicit loop to set the other values of the SplFixedArray if you don't want them to be `null` (sadly, no prefillValue can be passed to the constructor).

Answer (score 1):

Like every other array affectation :

```
$myarray[1] = "";
```

Or, if you mean fill the gaps in the array :

```
$i = 0;
ksort($myarray);
foreach($myarray as $k => $v) {
    while($i < $k) {
        // if $i < $k we're missing some keys.
        $myarray[$i] = '';
        $i ++;
    }
    $i++;
}
ksort($myarray);
```

edit: added the sorting to avoid removing values.

Comment: this will then remove the email address.

Comment: @RobertPitt no, the e-mail address has the key `2`

Comment: a while in a foreach for this? and what about double-incrementing $i?

Comment: @fabrik with double-incrementing, cases with gaps greater than one will pose problems. This way, we can have a 10 index gap and everything will run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array value based on the key.

`$array[1] = ''`

Comment: And what if there are zillions of empty keys?

Comment: I think he was thinking more along the lines of achieving this dynamically.

Comment: I was basing it off of his example array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

function array_fill_empty($array, $default = "") {
    if(!is_array($array)) return array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if(!isset($array[$i])) $array[$i] = $default;
    }
    return $array;
}

$array1 = array(0 => 'Bill', 2 => 'billy@kid.com');
$array1 = array_fill_empty($array1);
var_dump($array1);

?>
```

Comment: should work just tested it ... lol sorry left the testing code in there